# What is the upload limit on soundcloud

Tags: soundcloud

I sometimes get the error: { error_message: 'Sorry, you\'ve exceeded your upload limit.' } when I post sound files to soundcloud, using their http api.

I couldn't find any explanation for this 'upload limit' in their documentations.

Does anyone know if it's a daily limit? or a size limit? or a combination of both?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual files cannot exceed 500mb [Uploading Audio Files](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#uploading)

However, I'd imagine this relates to your overall limit for uploading audio to SoundCloud based on the plan attached to the account you're posting to i.e exceeding the 2 hours provided by the free plan.

The API doesn't appear to provide a property for the remaining time provided to the user, although you could infer this from [user]plan & looping through all of their tracks and summing each [track]duration (although probably not advised).

Answer (score 2):

Sparko is mostly right. The only difference is that you can tell how much remaining time you have by requesting the current user details (GET /me) and you'll there will be a key called `upload_seconds_remaining`.

Free users get 2 hours. Pro gets 4 hours. Pro Unlimited is unlimited. Regardless of the plan, individual tracks also can not be longer than ~6.5hrs (I forget the exact number)